# problem with obfs4proxy and apparmor (solved)

Tags: bridge, obfs4, apparmor

Finally yesterday I installed ubuntu 16.04 and after that I installed tor and obfs4. I add this line at the end of torrc file:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge obfs4 82.243.119.185:990 B08238781C2CD80DBD95AEABEB6F6C75F2E2CEB6 cert=1udeMlFNs3sJ20zwpPE6nShZqqwDb3F1ET4KzfSfD+fktkue9zNx9H3t+yLCPAsg+6UTUA iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 192.36.31.173:42912 33DCA3BAD915D0F04CFAC6DF47B1BEB9E95E5C3A cert=3sBbfmp4fpIPpinXWbjZiVp+zWrK1kEUfmqNJNfszb8SXS+DeaVS4vQyvK7/fkU/TEPqVQ iat-mode=0
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy --managed
```

But it didn't work, here is the log:

```
tail -f /var/log/tor/log
Jun 08 21:33:04.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
Jun 08 21:33:04.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
Jun 08 21:33:05.000 [warn] Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('Operation not permitted').
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '82.243.119.185:990' using pluggable transport 'obfs4', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs4'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Can't connect to bridge; PT_MISSING; count 1; recommendation warn; host B08238781C2CD80DBD95AEABEB6F6C75F2E2CEB6 at 82.243.119.185:990)
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '192.36.31.173:42912' using pluggable transport 'obfs4', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs4'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Can't connect to bridge; PT_MISSING; count 2; recommendation warn; host 33DCA3BAD915D0F04CFAC6DF47B1BEB9E95E5C3A at 192.36.31.173:42912)
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '94.242.249.2:47282' using pluggable transport 'obfs4', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs4'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Jun 08 21:33:06.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Can't connect to bridge; PT_MISSING; count 3; recommendation warn; host 52C5F1C15DCF6DAC47556EC1D4EC4BE5B24BDEC7 at 94.242.249.2:47282)
```

I'm beginner could you please help me where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have obfs4proxy installed? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/obfs4proxy`?

Comment: Yes I installed that. '-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6485536 مارس  22 16:09 /usr/bin/obfs4proxy'

Answer (score 5):

In your `torrc` there is the line

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy --managed
```

Furthermoer the log file states:

> Jun 08 21:33:05.000 [warn] Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('Operation not permitted').

According to the manpage of obfs4proxy there is no option `--managed`. This was used for `obfsproxy`. So if you delete the option `--managed` and restart Tor, it will start and use obfs4proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You could fix your problem with apparmor like this:

First open `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor` with your favorite editor (with root user)

- sudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor

Then change the `/usr/bin/obfs4proxy PUx,` to `/usr/bin/obfs4proxy ix,` and save it!

And after that reboot

Comment: Could you explain what the change from `PUx` to `ix` does? It might help future readers.

Comment: @JensKubieziel
Its about permissions.For example `PU` means:
`**P** - exec to profile that matches executable name, with environment variable scrubbing.`
`**U** - exec to unconfined, with environment variable scrubbing.`
For more look at [http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference](AppArmor Core Policy Reference)

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian
  /usr/bin/obfsproxy PUx,
  /usr/bin/obfs4proxy ix,
this is mine and still not work !